# Alternatives to Upload Images from Google Forms to Firebase

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have been trying to determine the best approach to upload images from google forms to firebase. Currently, based on this [Google thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135828271), there is currently no way to grab the image.

Is there an alternative to grab an image from the Google Form and upload it to Firebase?

Comment: Have your tried the `onSubmit` trigger?

Comment: And yet I have found a way to grab the images that I upload from forms and move them to the appropriate folders and change there names.  So I suggest you learn more.

Comment: @Dmitry: i am referring to an approach that allows me to grab an image from the google forms.

Comment: @Cooper: can you please provide the approach on how you were able to grab a an image from the form?

Comment: The form shows you where it uploads the images too.  Get the id and your done.

Comment: I know. My question stands.

Answer (score 0):

#### The Link to the upload folder is provided in the Form Editor

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing. This is not what I am looking for. I will clarify my question so its clearer on what I am asking.